# Efficiently filtering duplicates out from a multiway join of three tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three tables with many:many relationships as follows:

```
Tag
+-------+---------+
| TagID | ThemeID |
+-------+---------+
| t1    | th1     |
+-------+---------+
| t2    | th2     |
+-------+---------+
| t3    | th3     |
+-------+---------+
| t4    | th1     |
+-------+---------+
| t5    | th2     |
+-------+---------+

Theme
+---------+------------+
| ThemeID | ThemeStuff |
+---------+------------+
| th1     | ts1        |
+---------+------------+
| th2     | ts2        |
+---------+------------+
| th3     | ts3        |
+---------+------------+
| th4     | ts4        |
+---------+------------+

UserTag
+-------+--------+
| TagID | UserID |
+-------+--------+
| t1    | Fred   |
+-------+--------+
| t2    | Fred   |
+-------+--------+
| t4    | Fred   |
+-------+--------+
| t4    | Frank  |
+-------+--------+
```

Given a specific UserID I am trying to retrieve the associated Theme records for those Tags and retain a single relevant TagID value as a reference for how I got to that Theme record.

The simple approach I started with was:

```
    SELECT a.TagID, c.ThemeID, c. Themestuff FROM UserTags a, Tags b, Theme c 
        WHERE a.UserID = 'Fred' AND a.TagID = b.TagID AND b.ThemeID = c.ThemeID
```

The trouble with it is that I am getting results for Fred that include the same Theme records multiple times if Fred used different tags to access them over the course of a week:

```
+------------------------------+
| Simple Results               |
+-------+---------+------------+
| TagID | ThemeID | ThemeStuff |
+-------+---------+------------+
| t1    | th1     | ts1        |
+-------+---------+------------+
| t2    | th2     | ts2        |
+-------+---------+------------+
| t4    | th1     | ts1        |
+-------+---------+------------+
```

I would like to only see a single Theme record that is a match, **with one of the TagIDs that mapped to it -** I don't care which specific TagID mapped to it as long as I have one of them that was associated with that user.

In other words, the target result should like like this:

```
+------------------------------+
| Target  Results              |
+-------+---------+------------+
| TagID | ThemeID | ThemeStuff |
+-------+---------+------------+
| t1    | th1     | ts1        |
+-------+---------+------------+
| t2    | th2     | ts2        |
+-------+---------+------------+ 
or
+------------------------------+
| Target  Results              |
+-------+---------+------------+
| TagID | ThemeID | ThemeStuff |
+-------+---------+------------+
| t4    | th1     | ts1        |
+-------+---------+------------+
| t2    | th2     | ts2        |
+-------+---------+------------+
```

I tried filtering it with DISTINCT on nested subqueries and it quickly turned into a mess that still wasn't quite right. I feel like there must be s simple solution out there that I am missing. Would appreciate any insight...

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Thank you, updated to reflect the feedback.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want duplicates for themes, then I would suggest `exists`:

```
select th.*
from themes th
where exists (select 1
              from tags t join
                   usertags ut
                   on tu.tagid = t.tagid
              where t.themeid = th.themeid and
                    u.userid = 'Fred'
             );
```

Comment: Thanks for the speedy response. This is almost what I need, but it omits a tagid value from the results, and as noted above I need at least one tagid value along with the themestuff content - I just don't care which one. I just updated the problem above to ensure it is clearer. Is there a clean way to pull the tagid value up to the outer select? Should I run two nested queries (one for the themes and the other for the tags) and intersect the results? Never worked in SQL, learning it on the fly. CM5 OS was easier.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite an answer, but a solution nonetheless. After wasting another hour on trying to get a clean select from the three tables, I finally coded up a routine to eliminate the redundancies from the query results.

```
    // Sync function to remove duplicate themes from the result
    // Returns the clean list
    function reduceSet(rawOutput) {
        let lastID = null;

        for (var i = rawOutput.length-1; i >= 0; i--) {
            if (rawOutput[i].theme_id != lastID) {
                lastID = rawOutput[i].theme_id;
            } else {
                rawOutput.splice(i, 1);
            }
        }
        return rawOutput;
    }
```

Since the resultant data set is not expected to be over 100 records, this is probably fine. If anyone does happen to have a real answer, I would still like to know it.